# Determine if Python script is being executed locally or as CGI

Tags: python, cgi

Let's say I have a basic Python script, `test.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "<html>Hello world!</html>"
```

How would one determine if the script is being executed locally, e.g.:

```
python test.py
```

Or being called via a web browser, e.g. visiting:

```
http://example.com/test.py
```

This doesn't seem to be addressed in [the documentation for the `cgi` module](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html). I thought there might be a difference in the result of `cgi.FieldStorage()` but there doesn't seem to be one.

The only way I can think to do it is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "<html>Hello world!</html>"

if 'REQUEST_METHOD' in os.environ :
    print "This is a webpage"
else :
    print "This is not a webpage"
```

Is this the best and/or most ideal method? Why/why not?

Comment: Another idea: Do it like `/usr/bin/python myscript.py mysupersecret` every time you run the script locally, and then check if `sys.argv[1] == "mysupersecret"`, then this is called locally. When called from CGI `sys.argv` will not have the args (unless you have set them up, in which case you already know what to do).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That looks like the best method. There isn't much difference between being called from the command-line and being started by the web server following a HTTP request, except for the CGI environment variables, like REQUEST_METHOD.